# Print statement in Pluto.jl

Tags: julia, pluto.jl

I am trying to making print statement work in Pluto.jl. Right now when I execute `println` it prints to console, using `PlutoUI` extension to makes the print statement work but not in for loop.
Is there a way to print in for loop to Pluto.jl notebook?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `with_terminal()` like so:

[image]

(the code is:

```
using PlutoUI
with_terminal() do 
    for i in 1:10
        println("Hi, I'm $i")
    end
end
```